# Jenkins can't generate HTML reports with htmlpublisher

Tags: html, jenkins, report, php-codebrowser

I'm having a heck of a time trying to publish any HTML report with [htmlpublisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin).

My input looks like this:

[image]

And the 404 looks like this:

[image]

The report is definitely generated in `build/`.  I've visually compared my config.xml file to a known working example and it's apparently the same.  The entry in `jobs/` is there, with the correct name and documentation.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I've checked the "keep past HTML reports" box, unchecked it, played with the paths, read the (poor) documentation but I can't seem to get it working.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **developers of Jenkins** has confirmed that this issue is related to the version **1.529** and **it is solved in 1.530**.

Comment: Still not working. Tried specifying the full path to the html file in the directory to archive and still a failed build: `E:/test/test.html is not a directory.`  I tried a few other variations based on this idea and another clue came out: `Specified code directory 'E:/E:/test/ does not exist.` which shows the base path is correct, and a relative path should be used for the directory to archive.  Looks like a problem in the redirect controller in Jenkins, maybe...any further thoughts?

Comment: Nope, reinstalled everything and still no-go.

Comment: are you tried with sample html(with new job)? my o/p is still the same . after installing the html plugin restart the Jenkins, i think it will definitely work,don't know about your project,but i am sure that the html publisher plugin will work and i checked it with another machine (installed jenkins locally) with sample html and is working fine :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried everything I could think of, including restarting the service and even reinstalling it. The plugin *should* be working - I've installed about 10 other plugins, with no worries.  I think like @Tindron was saying it may be a version problem.

Comment: my jenkins version is 1.522,i did not upgraded my jenkins.may be that's why i can't figure your issue,and here i just explain about the html publisher plugin to get a basic idea because you specified about the plugin's poor documentation in your question

Comment: @steve: i faced the same issue after upgrade, informed this issue to jenkins through the JIRA,"the fix should be out in 1.530." this is the replay that i got,

Comment: Ha! It works now! Thanks to you and Tindron.  You may want to change your original answer though.

Answer (score 4):

What version of Jenkins are you running?  I'm seeing this issue on all of my projects since updating to 1.529.  The files are being copied to jobs/ correctly as you mentioned.

The answer you accepted is incorrect and contradicts the documentation at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

EDIT:  The issue has been resolved in 1.530: https://jenkins-ci.org/changelog
I've updated and I'm not seeing 404s anymore.

Comment: yep, 1.529.  And yes, you're right that it contradicts the docs, but I thought he knew something I didn't...anyway I'll wait for some more results. Hopefully you're on to something because I've spent way too much time on this. :)

Comment: @Sumeshk - ok thanks, unfortunately still no definitive answer...you got a lot of rep though for your help :)

Comment: @steve : i am not only looking for the reputation, i am here for learning and sharing knowledge

Comment: Yes, I appreciate all of those points and thanks again for your help.  I didn't downvote your answer, I removed the "accept", because my question hasn't been answered yet.  Nothing personal.  If it *was* personal, I'd accept your answer, because you've been so helpful.  But in boolean terms, I can't accept (yet) because it's not the solution.

Comment: :) @steve, this is not a personal issue, i got 1 down vote for this answer, i think its you, no need to aceept my answer if it is not able to solve your issue, now i am going to upgrade my jenkins and i wil try to solve ypur isse , if it is solved you can aceept my answer other wise no need to accept my answer